# mySQL query to find object that is in relation with all objects. No aggregation operation

Tags: mysql, sql

Query to find gadgets that are in relation with all gadgets. Without using any
aggregation operation.

```
CREATE TABLE `gadget`(
 `gadget` VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE `relation`(
 `gadget1` VARCHAR(10),
 `relation` boolean,
 `gadget2` VARCHAR(10),
);
```

The thought with table `relation`, is that gadget1 has relation with gadget2 if true.

Comment: Please add input and expected output

Comment: It is common NOT EXISTS exercise.

Comment: Please revise your SQL so it executes.

Comment: Are *all* possible gadget pairs in the relation table? Are they mirrored (`A | yes | B` *and* `B | yes | A`) or is every pair only contained once (only either `A | yes | B` *or* `B | yes | A`)?

Comment: Why don't you want to use aggrgation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gets the pairs that are NOT related:

```
select g1.gadget as gadget1, g2.gadget as gadget2
from gadget g1 join
     gadget g2
     on g1.gadget <> g2.gadget left join -- presumably gadgets are not related to themselves       
     relation r
     on r.gadget1 = g1.gadget and r.gadget2 = g2.gadget
 where r.gadget1 is null
```

Then, you want the gadgets not in this list:

```
select g.gadget
from gadget g left join
     (select g1.gadget as gadget1, g2.gadget as gadget2
      from gadget g1 join
           gadget g2
           on g1.gadget <> g2.gadget left join
           relation r
           on r.gadget1 = g1.gadget and r.gadget2 = g2.gadget
      where r.gadget1 is null
     ) gg
     on g.gadget = gg.gadget1
where gg.gadget1 not null;
```

Comment: @Akina . . . I don't usually use `minus` for that purpose anyway, so I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By the presence of the column `relation` in the table `relation` (not so good practice to have a column with the same name as the table), which can be `true` or `false`, I assume that this table contains all possible pairs of gadgets.
If this is the case then all you need is `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select g.gadget 
from gadget g
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from relation r 
  where g.gadget in (r.gadget1, r.gadget2) and not r.relation
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ZGVR38aGreXfJmu1wJchk/0).